# JSP: How to add value in a list with onClick or onSubmit event?

Tags: java, jsp

Hi everyone I am new to JSP. I'm working on a simple activity where I can add add a user on a list and display it. The displaying of the list of users works fine but I have problem in adding a user.

The code below displays the List of Users:

```html
<div id="userList">
            <h3>List of Users</h3>
            <ul>
                <% for (User user : data.getUsers())
                    {%>
                <li>
                    -<%= user.getFirstName()%> 
                    <%= user.getLastName()%> 
                    <br>Address: <%= user.getAddress()%>
                    <br>Age: <%= user.getAge()%>
                </li>
                <%}%>
            </ul>
</div>
```

The Code below is the form to add user:

```html
<form onsubmit="addToList()">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>Add User</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    First Name: <input id="firstNameField" type="Text" ></input>
                    Last Name: <input id="lastNameField" type="Text"></input>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Age: <input id="ageField" type="Text" ></input>
                    Address: <input id="addressField" type="Text"></input>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="submit" onclick="addToList()">Submit</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

And here is the code that handle the event:

```js
<--Javascript-->
<script>
  function addToList()
    {
      <%data.addUsers(request.getParameter("firstNameField"), request.getParameter("lastNameField"), request.getParameter("ageField"), request.getParameter("addressField"));%>   <%-- data.adduser adds user to sample data --> 
    }
</script>
```

```js
<--JQuery-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
        <%
            data.addUsers(request.getParameter("firstNameHidden"), request.getParameter("lastNameHidden"), request.getParameter("ageHidden"), request.getParameter("addressHidden"));
        %>
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run it there is a new user added with null values but when I try to submit again it will not trigger the event. Can someone enlighten me if I'm doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't mix JSP scriptlet code with Javascript.  Have a look at jquery instead.  Also do yourself a favour a learn about JSTL as well

Comment: Really? Okay, I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Never tried it myself, but according to [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4509352/2310289) you can have JSTL in JS

Comment: First of all remove the minus from this code `-<%= user.getFirstName()%> `

Comment: Hi, I try with the same approach using JQuery unfortunately the output is still the same. I'll add the snippet. I am now reading JSTL documentation.

Comment: Hi the minus is just an indication of each user. It's just a replacement of the bullet because I disabled it in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution in this problem. I tried using Servlets to process the request in the form and it works!

```js
 <form action="AddUser"> <-- AddUser is a servlet-->
            First Name: <input name="firstNameField" type="text">
            Last Name: <input name="lastNameField" type="text">

            Age: <input name="ageField" type="text">
            Address: <input name="addressField" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

And in the AddUser servlet I display all the User including the newly added user.

```js
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
        {
            // reading the user input 
            out.append("<ul>");
            for(User user: data.getUsers())
            {
                out.append("<li>" +user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName()
                        +"<br>Address:"+user.getAddress()
                        +"<br>Age:"+user.getAge()+"</li>");
            }
            out.append("</ul>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also don't forget to add the servlet in the web.xml. I'm using netbeans so it automatically adds it in the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JSP scriptlet code with Javascript. You should call a AJAX API on server side from Javascript on addToList event. On the server side, you can add User in list and then from javascript on success, refresh the page so that JSP will load the new data.