# Reading bean list using jstl and assigning to javascript variable in facelets

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, jstl, facelets

I am using facelet and draw function has jstl tag:

```
               <ui:define name="content" >
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/paths.js"/> 
                <h:outputScript name="js/graphics/draw.js"/>
```

### Tag to be evaluated when function is called(is that possible)?

```
function showMap(){

 var data = {
        <c:forEach items="${list.KPI}" var="ctag" varStatus="loop">        
            '${ctag.USTER}': ${ctag.Value}
            ${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    }     
}
```

### Error:

[image]

Is it possible to use jstl with facelets? Why am i getting this error? I am using there links:

1) [is it possible for javascript to extract value from cforeach tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506816/is-possible-javascript-extract-value-from-cforeach-tag)

2) [populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely JSTL works in Facelets. There are only some technical implications which can only be understood by *really* understanding the Facelets lifecycle: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

As to your concrete problem, you most likely forgot to declare the JSTL taglib in the XML namespace.

```html
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

Not doing so would cause the JSTL tags not being interpreted at all and end up in a syntax error in the generated HTML/JS code because JSTL tags are not recognizeable by the webbrowser as valid HTML/JS code. Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source*. You should **not** see any unparsed/plain JSTL tags in there.

Comment: Thanks. Is this method only one time process i.e js is evaluated once. Now if I would like to call the js function then it would return same result as it was first loaded with it was not useful for variable result am I right? Should I make switch to gson?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're concretely asking, but I believe that this has nothing to do with the initial question. Feel free to ask a new question wherein you elaborate the concrete functional requirement in more detail.

Comment: Thank you ! I opened more detailed query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753112/gson-with-servlet .